# Convert a git subproject into a regular folder

Tags: git, github

I have a subdirectory inside my git project that already has a .git repository in it. Historical reasons, no particular planning.

I then tried to push this larger project into github.

It did not push the subdirectory with .git as I hoped it would.

I need to push it, so I figured out the quickest way to do it would be to remove the .git folder from the subproject, right?

Wrong. Git is still treating that folder as a subproject and not committing (and consequently, not pushing).

I just need to push the whole thing upstream, one way or the other. How do I do it?

Comment: Just curious: is there a way to automatically commit all subprojects when the main project is committed? Ditto add .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably also need to stop tracking the file.  Try `git rm --cached filename_here`.  Then `git add` the changes, then `git commit`

Comment: Just wanted to repost my question for you from another comment: is there a way to automatically commit all subprojects when the main project is committed? Ditto git add .

Comment: do you mean sub project, or sub folder? you should only have one .git per repo

Comment: you can do git commit -a to add all without needing to do the git add . command